# Get specific dataTable cell values in View (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to find a way to access specific cells in a DataTable in View. The DataTable was created in controller.
Code in conroller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _ls()
{    
    var getXMLlivescore = new HtmlDocument();
    getXMLlivescore.Load("D://lscopy.xml");

    DataTable matchTable = new DataTable();
    matchTable.Columns.Add("put2forEventOr1", typeof(int));
    matchTable.Columns.Add("country", typeof(string));
    ...
    matchTable.Columns.Add("min", typeof(string));
    matchTable.Columns.Add("extramin", typeof(string));

    foreach (HtmlNode match in category.SelectNodes(".//match")){
        //code to get xml tags    
        matchTable.Rows.Add(put2forEventOr1, country, ....., min, extramin);
    }
    return PartialView(matchTable);
}
```

and the partialView code:

```
<table>
    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
    {        
       //get cell in row[0]
       @if (row[0] == 3){
           do some work
        }
    }
</table>
```

How can I iterate through DataTable cells in view and get specific cells?

Comment: Should I use something different from dataTable? Like a list? pass every row as a list element separated by commas ? and then iterate through list in View? it seems much more easier, i will try it

Comment: Why do you need to pass data as a DataTable if you actually reading values from XML?

Comment: I need to add more info than the given xml. I also need to present the data in a more organized way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand why do you need to use a `DataTable`. You can always create a class with structure you need. It will be much easier to us simple POCO's in your views.

You haven't provided your XML so I made some examples for very simple version:

```
<Elements>
   <Element>
      <Country>Peru</Country>
      <Min>20</Min>
   </Element>
   <Element>
      <Country>Armenia</Country>
      <Min>9</Min>
   </Element>
</Elements>
```

For such XML you can create a class that will represent an `Element`:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public string NotXmlProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use your method of reading XML or for example this one:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
IEnumerable<Element> elements = xDoc
    .Descendants("Element")
    .Select(x => new Element
    {
        Country = x.Element("Country").Value,
        Min = Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("Min").Value),
        NotXmlProperty = "Value"
    });
```

After that accessing your data in the view should be very simple:

```
@model IEnumerable<Element>

<table>
    @foreach(var element in Model) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@element.Country</td>
            <td>@element.Min</td>
            <td>@element.NotXmlProperty</td>
        </tr>
    }
<table>
```